# How can i know the frequency range of electronic device?

Tags: frequency, frequency-measurement

How do I know the frequency of an electronic device? For example, we all know that the microwave is working under 2.4 GHz frequency. So, if I want to know the other frequency range for other devices, how do I go about it? I tried to look for example on my cordless phone and I didn't see anything that mentioned the range the phone is working in.

The other question is, do all the same electronic devices (i.e. all microwave) operate on the same frequency?

Comment: No, GHz! Capital "G", capital "H", lowercase "z". "Hz" is derived from a person's name (Hertz) and then abbreviated units are *always* with a capital.

Comment: Well some methods could be finding which standard the device uses and then reading on the frequency range of the standard. Maybe some information could be obtained from the certification marks on the device?

Comment: Maybe pronouncing it like Back to the FUture as a JiggaHurts....  Person whose names are used in units are always Capitalized in the "Proper" method ( see Word processor ) meaning 1st letter is capped only. But of course there are always renegades who disrespect those people such as q8y and use lower case. Frankly I like mΩ because milli and Mega are different and **KB and Kb** are different too but Byte and Bit are not personal names, well maybe they are now for some... make sense Q8Y?  If the unit does not say, then check the FCC tag number and look it up.

Comment: Assuming you have an EMI problem at home with Wifi..... let me take a SWAG....  All consumer microwave ovens are the same but not interfering with WiFi but some cordless phones occupy the same bands as Wifi if it says 2.4GHz, so switch your router channel to 0 from 6 and try that. Then ring your phone and test it. Its the ring that drops the WiFi

Comment: The only general method to find out what harmonics are present in any circuit is to measure them with a frequency counter and EMI box.

No, not all devices of a certain type operate in the same band.

Comment: In the USA, devices are registered with the FCC, and you can [look up the FCC ID](https://fccid.io/frequency-explorer.php) to determine the operating frequency.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's JiggaWatts, 1.21 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cell phones operate in the 800-900MHz frequency range with some services being provided around 1.8 to 1.9 GHz (PCS). Cell phones transmit between 0.1 and 1 watt depending on the service. Cell towers are typically limited to 500 Watts of effective radiated power (ERP) per channel for large towers and less than 100 watts for smaller towers in urban areas. Micro and pico installations on the sides of buildings or between floors may have ERPs of less than 10 watts per channel.

No, different types of electronic devices do not work in the same frequency. If they were, then there would be a massive amount of interference.
But similar devices do operate in the same frequency. Microwaves must operate in 2.4 GHz, and WiFi operates in 2.4 GHz and 5GHz.
Model cars and boats use 27MHz, while model planes use 72MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Any system makes use of both the physics and the industrial economics.

It would be pointless to have phone systems working on different frequencies as they would not work together.

Frequency bands are controlled by international organisations, they consider the physics and practical implications of choosing one frequency over another.  Often for very historic reasons.

Microwaves ALL work at 2.4GHz, this is because 2.4GHz is the resonant frequency of water, and a lot of food stuff contains water.  Hit a water molecule with 2.4GHz and it resonates, getting hot.

WiFi devices (and phones etc) work at 2.4GHz because the international organisations (mentioned earlier) realised (or should I say wrongly though) that the because of microwave ovens causing interfearence the band had no commercial value, it was set asside for unlicenced "Industrial Scientific and Medical" purposes (ISM).  However clever people worked out how to help prevent the interfearence causing trouble to Wifi, phones etc so it became usefull rather than useless!